# VHDL Vector Array

Tags: syntax, vhdl

I am attempting to create an array of vectors in VHDL however I am getting an error in modelsim. 
I have:

```
type   read_data_array is array (0 to 73) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);    
signal reg_data_stream              : read_data_array;
```

I store data into the array by:

```
reg_data_stream(counter) <= read_data;
```

"read_data" is that of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) and "counter" is a basic counter that increments from 0.

Comment: `subtype byte is std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);  type  read_data_array is array (0 to 73) of byte;` Or tell us what the actual error message says...

Comment: And the declaration for read_data and count as well as the actual error message.

Comment: Out of the top of my head, I'd say that counter is not an integer and you're missing a to_integer(...) statement, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To index an array or a vector, VHDL expects an integer. If counter is a  `std_logic_vector`, try:

```
to_integer(unsigned(counter)) <= read_data;
```